Is it possible to import thermal camera data into the FLIR ResearchIR software from a CSV file?
We have academic partners who require data that can be processed in ResearchIR. I know it's possible to export data from ResearchIR to CSV, but it seems that the file formats that it can open are very restricted.  Is there any publically available file format that I might use to process as CSV file into FLIR ResearchIR readable form?
